# Recent Four Weeks Average Sales based on a condition in R

Tags: r, if-statement, average, lag

I have dataset of promoted products during  certain weeks, I want to compute the avg sales of products during promotion to non promotion sales for the past 4 non promo (indicated by flag)weeks. If the transaction is during non promo period , we should take the sale as it is we have to take avg of sales of recent non promo weeks sales, they may be non continous.

Please note that the

```
structure(list(Product_group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), Promo = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    Week = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("2017-01-01", 
    "2017-01-02", "2017-01-04", "2017-01-05", "2017-01-06", "2017-01-08", 
    "2017-01-09"), class = "factor"), Sales = c(50, 50, 60, 70, 
    50, 50)), .Names = c("Product_group", "Promo", "Week", "Sales"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

head(df)
  Product_group Promo       Week Sales
1             A     0 2017-01-01    50
2             A     0 2017-01-02    50
3             A     1 2017-01-02    60
4             A     0 2017-01-04    70
5             A     0 2017-01-05    50
6             A     1 2017-01-06    50
```

I am looking for an output like

```
          Product_group Promo       Week Sales Avg Pre Promo Sales
    1             A     0 2017-01-01    50      50 # Since it is non promo
    2             A     0 2017-01-02    50      50 
    3             A     1 2017-01-02    60      50 # 100/2
    4             A     0 2017-01-04    70      70 
    5             A     0 2017-01-05    50      50
    6             A     1 2017-01-06    50      55 # (50 +70 + 50 + 50 )/4
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. I think now it is doing what you are after. Let me know if that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Promo == 1`, I look at the indices for which `Promo` is zero. Then selects maximum last four weeks to get the average.

```
  df <- rbind(df, df) # get more rows to data

  df$AvgPrePromoSales <- 
   sapply(1 : nrow(df), function(x) if(df$Promo[x] == 1) {
        ind <- which(df[1:x,]$Promo == 0)
        mean(df$Sales[ind[max(1, length(ind) - 3) : length(ind)]])
      } else {
        df$Sales[x] 
      })

df[, c(2, 4, 5)]
#      Promo Sales AvgPrePromoSales
# 1      0    50               50
# 2      0    50               50
# 3      1    60               50
# 4      0    70               70
# 5      0    50               50
# 6      1    50               55
# 7      0    50               50
# 8      0    50               50
# 9      1    60               55
# 10     0    70               70
# 11     0    50               50
# 12     1    50               55
```

Comment: excellent answer, but is there any way to limit the mean of sales to only recent 4 weeks non promo, as of now it will take the mean of all the non promo weeks earlier to a promo week

Comment: I made a mistake; it was taking the average of last *five* non-promo weeks. Now, it should take only the last four.

Comment: a really succint answer, I had done the exact login but using for loop instead of sapply , but I guess this would be much faster